# Place to store PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is the Below question solution correct for where should the PL/SQL be stored.

You want to create a PL/SQL block cof code that calculates discounts on customer orders. - This code will be invoked from several places,but only within the program unit ORDERTOTAL.
What is the most appropriate location to store the code that calculates the discounts?

```
A. A stored procedure on the server.
B. A block of code in PL/SQL library.
C. A standalone procedure on the client machine.
D. A block of code in the body of the program unit ORDERTOTAL.
E. A local subprogram defined within the program unit ORDERTOTAL.

ANSWER: E
```

Comment: can I know,which gentleman down voted on wht basis,so tht I correct tht nxt time

Comment: Whts the CORRECT answer,is the E correct,bcoz I have confusion with A also

Comment: Another -1 for "wht", "tht", "nxt", and "bcoz".

Comment: Is this question in the context of Oracle Forms?

Comment: Down voted (and to close) because, as an image, the question isn't searchable in any practical terms, so won't be any use to anyone. Also the context of the question is missing.

Comment: Thanks alot for making me realize my mistake,next time I consider that indexing factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ranzo notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364122/place-to-store-pl-sql-block/7364767#7364767) several of the other answers are are also plausible.  So, why is **E** the correct answer?   Because the question asks for *the most appropriate location* for the code.

Let's break it down.

The logic needs to be called from several places.  It is therefore necessary to define it as its own function (because we don't want to repeat the same code).

At the same time, the customer discount logic is only called from the ORDERTOTAL program unit.  Hence we don't want to expose it as a standalone procedure or a packaged function, which could be called by other programs.  That rules out **A** and **B**.

So the best place to put it is **E**, the declaration section of the ORDERTOTAL program.  Something like:

```
 create procedure ordertotal
     (custid in pls_integer
      , orderid in pls_integer)
 is
     ln_running_total number;
     ....
     function calc_discount 
        (custid in pls_integer)
        return number
     is
  ....
```

Now if ORDERTOTAL were a packaged procedure, we would have the choice to make CALC_DISCOUNT() a private function (defined in the body but not declared in the spec).   But generally speaking its better to keep the scope as tight as possible, unless there is a reasonable chance the function will be used by other procedures in the future.

For the record, **C** is wrong because stuff declared on the client side is not accessible to the server, and **D** is wrong because it would not compile.

---

While searching for a text version of this question, I found a PDF version [here](http://www.net130.com/Class/oracle_cert_bible/ActualTest%20Oracle%201Z0-147%20v01.29.04.pdf) which gives the correct answer as **A**. 8-)  And another site offering pirated exams says the correct answer is **B**. So the good news is, people who think they can hack the tests by simply learning the answers are going to FAIL.

Answer (score 0):

Everything except "C" is plausible.  These Oracle tests have descended into minutia, in an effort to make them harder.  I know several good Oracle DBAs who can't pass them, because they are not about concepts but about jargon and trickiness.

E is the best answer, it localizes the subroutine in the calling program.  The key word is local.

Of course, it is also stored on the DB server (A), it is in fact a block of code (B--although "library" isn't PL/SQL speak), and it is in fact a block of code within ORDERTOTAL (D).

Good luck on your tests, and make sure to focus on the concepts.

Comment: 'libraries' are an Oracle Forms concept where common Forms PL/SQL procedure are stored in a separate file.

Comment: @Gary - I'm pretty certain it's using library to mean "PL/SQL package"

Comment: Actually only A and E are plausible.